# How do I block Internet for an app using an apparmor custom profile?

Tags: 14.04, firewall, apparmor

I'm trying to block internet access for an app because it always asks for purchase or update even though it's free. I created an apparmor profile for that app and enforced it but after enforcing, the app is not starting.

This is the profile in `/etc/apparmor.d/opt.sublime_text.sublime_text`:

```
/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text {

        deny network inet,
        deny network inet6,
        deny network raw,  #include <abstractions/base>

        /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text mr,
        /opt/sublime-text/ rw,
        /home/shady/.config/sublime-text-3/ rw,
}
```

I included the directories that this app may need. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You need much more to launch this type of app. When there is something missing in your profile it has no access to it. `Sublimetext` must have access to things like :

> - X server
> - system fonts
> - Xauthority file
> - dconf
> - glib
> - etc ...

The best and easiest way to create your own profile is to install `apparmor-utils`

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils
```

then create your profile using generate profile tool:

```
sudo aa-genprof /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text
```

In this moment it creates sublimetext profile in `/etc/apparmor.d/` and is listening for program actions. This profile is in `complain` mode and it is logging to `/var/log/syslog`. Now you need to launch your sublimetext and make some actions like opening and saving files, etc.. all this acions will be saved in log file which is used by `aa-genprof`for creating rules. When you are done with activities hit `s` key and answer for questions about **access** or **deny** to your resources. When done use `f` key for saving your newly created profile and turning it to `enforce` mode.

---

However it is quite easy this tool is not working perfectly. It will not include everything and you must add something manually like access to `X`
In `/etc/apparmor.d/opt.sublime_text.sublime_text`:

```
include <abstractions/X>
```

If any changes were made you have to reload config file:

```
sudo apparmor_parser r /etc/apparmor.d/opt.sublime_text.sublime_text
```